# Ликбез перед чтением Д.Э. Кнут "Искусство программирования"

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Какие конкретно виды/области математики (или может быть еще чего) надо знать, чтобы хорошо, в полной мере понять четырехтомник Д.Э. Кнута "Искусство программирования"?

Comment: вот так незатейливо начался путь молодого падавана...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Итак стоит прочесть ["Конкретная математика. Математические основы информатики"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4721432/), потом ознакомиться с [Система программирования MMIXAL.NET](http://www.rsdn.ru/summary/5259.xml).
Для начала этого вполне достаточно + Вы должны иметь базовые знания основ алгоритмизации и программирования. По ходу чтения параллельно можно обращаться к Википедии за разъяснениями того или иного алгоритма.